# Ошибка в PDO MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ошибка:

```
PHP Strict Standards: Declaration of PDO_::prepare() should be compatible with PDO::prepare($statement, $options = NULL)
```

Код:

```
class PDO_ extends PDO {
   function __construct($dsn, $username, $password) {
      parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password);
      $this->setAttribute(PDO :: ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO :: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $this->setAttribute(PDO :: ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO :: FETCH_ASSOC);
   } 

   function prepare($sql) {
      $stmt = parent::prepare($sql, array(PDO :: ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS => array('PDOStatement_')));
      return $stmt;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны передавать в метод `prepare` 2 аргумента, как прописано в абстракции родительского класса.

```
function prepare($sql, $options = NULL) {
$stmt = parent :: prepare($sql, array(PDO :: ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS => array('PDOStatement_')
            ));
    return $stmt;
}
```

Можно разобрать, почему это происходит, на примере.

```
interface ITest {
    function foo0($bar);
    function foo1($bar);
}

class Test implements ITest {
    function foo0($bar) //тут всё будет нормально, сигнатура совпадает с сигнатурой метода в интерфейсе
    {
    }
    function foo1() //тут будет ошибка, в интерфейса прописан 1 параметр, а в реализации 0
    {
    }
}
```

То же самое с абстрактными методами абстрактных родительских классов.

**P.S.** Вы так же не можете менять тип передаваемых параметров в метод. Т.е. если в абстракции описано: `foo(array $arg)` - вы должны будете описать свой метод аналогично.

Comment: Не понял. Можно подробнее где и что передавать?

Comment: Спасибо. Галочку смогу поставить только через 2 минуты.